# Python Google drive API Insufficient Permission

Tags: python, api, drive

whenever I run my code in replit I'm getting

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from Google import Create_Service
#https://acloud.guru/forums/gcp-certified-associate-cloud-engineer/discussion/-Lh3ET0aNrv3FwNbNvh6/Insufficient%20Permission:%20Request%20had%20insufficient%20authentication%20scopes.
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly',]

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

folder_id = '1-WL_3B4nOlG-1yf-tP3fiYHNG8fj7JE7'

file_names = ['test.txt']
mime_types = ['text/plain'] 

media = MediaFileUpload('test.txt')

file_metadata = {
    'name': 'test.txt',
    'parents': [folder_id]
  }

service.files().create(
    body=file_metadata,
    media_body = media,
    fields = 'id'
    ).execute()
```

I receive this error:

```
credentials.json-drive-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly']
drive service created successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 29, in <module>
    service.files().create(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 937, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions', 'message': 'Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.'}]">
```

This is Google.py (which has Create_Service()) I got this code from a tutorial (this is the site/tutorial: https://learndataanalysis.org/google-drive-api-in-python-getting-started-lesson-1/)

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_console()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

What I'm trying to do is put test.txt in my folder on google drive.
If someone can help me would be really helpful! (be patient with me! I'm new to apis)

Comment: Can you provide the script of `Create_Service()`?

Comment: reply to @Tanaike - Hey! sry that I didn't put the code in the post! I've updated it now!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see the script. In your script, when you delete the file of `pickle_file` and only the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is set and reauthorize and then test the script, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that when you run your script, `pickle_file` file is created by authorizing the scopes. In my suggestion, I suggested removing the file and change the scope and reauthorize the scope. If you cannot still understand my comment, I apologize again.

Comment: Hi! I understood your comment but sadly it didn't work. Do you have more ideas maybe?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my suggestion was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.